# why C++ template type matching does not match to base class refrence, how can I make it match to base class refrence?

Tags: c++, templates, matching

Here is my C++ program code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct A { T x; };

template <typename T>
struct B:A<T> {  };

template <typename T>
void func(const A<T>& t) {
    cout<<"2"<<endl;
}

template <typename T>
void func(const T& t) {
    cout<<"1"<<endl;
}

int main() {
    B<int> b;
    func(b);
}
```

and it prints `1`. But what I expect is the function call prints `2`. Why `B<int>b` matches to `const T&` instead of `const A<T>&`. And how can I make it to match to `const A<T>&`?

Comment: For `void func(const T& t)`, `T` gets deduced as `B<int>`. `void func(const B<int>& t)` is a better match than `void func(const A<int>& t)`.

Comment: what should I change to make it match to `void func(const A<int>& t)` ?

Comment: You could write a proxy overload for each derived class, e.g. `template <typename T> void func(const B<T> &t) {func(static_cast<const A<T> &>(t));}`. Does that sound plausible?

Comment: Do all of the derived classes follow the same pattern: `template <typename T>
struct Derived : A<T>`?

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion helps in this scenario.  `A<T>` have many subclasses.  In my program, there are many places like `template<typename T1, typename T2> void func2(const A<T1>&p1, const A<T2>&p2)`. If I use proxy overload, many many proxy overloads have to be written because of a cartesian product.

Comment: Most of them follows the same pattern `template <typename T> struct Derived : A<T>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution 1

You could use `std::enable_if` and templated template parameters to get a better match for the function, like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct A { T x; };

template <typename T>
struct B:A<T> {  };

template <template <typename...> typename T, typename ...Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<A<Args...>, T<Args...>>>>
void func(const T<Args...>& t) {
    cout<<"2"<<endl;
}

template <typename T>
void func(const T& t) {
    cout<<"1"<<endl;
}


int main() {
    B<int> b;
    func(b);
    func(5);
}
```

However, this works only if `A` takes exactly the same template parameters as `T`. So if your `B` changes to ex.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct B : A<T> {}
```

this won't work anymore.

## Solution 2

Based on [Yakk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53977585/6205379) you can create a type trait that is more generic. This solution has no restrictions to its template parameters, like solution 1 does.

```
namespace detail 
{
    template <template <typename...> typename Base>
    struct template_base_detector
    {
        template <typename... Args>
        constexpr std::true_type operator()(Base<Args...>*);
        constexpr std::false_type operator()(...);
    };
} 

template <template <typename...> typename Base, typename T>
struct is_template_base_of 
    : decltype(std::declval<detail::template_base_detector<Base>>()((T*)nullptr)) {};

// since C++ 14
template <template <typename...> typename Base, typename T>
constexpr bool is_template_base_of_v = is_template_base_of<Base, T>::value;
```

Depending on your c++ version, you can use different approaches to utilize this trait.

#### C++ 17

Probably the most compact solution. Since C++ 17 constexpr if statements are allowed, which allows us to define just a single `func`:

```
template <typename T>
void func(const T& t) 
{
    if constexpr (is_template_base_of_v<A, T>)
        cout << 2 << endl;
    else
        cout << 1 << endl;
}
```

#### C++ 11 and 14

We have to fall back to tag dispatch:

```
namespace detail 
{
    template <typename T>
    void func(std::true_type, const T& t) 
    {
        std::cout << 2 << endl;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void func(std::false_type, const T& t) 
    {
        std::cout << 1 << endl;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void func(const T& t) 
{
    detail::func(is_template_base_of<A, T>{}, t);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tag dispatching.

First, we write a trait to detect if something has a template as a base:

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z>
  struct htb {
    template<class...Ts>
    constexpr std::true_type operator()(Z<Ts...>*){return {};}
    constexpr std::false_type operator()(...){return {};}
  };
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class X>
constexpr inline auto has_template_base = details::htb<Z>{}((X*)nullptr);
```

we can now use our new trait to tag dispatch:

```
namespace details{
  template <typename T>
  void func(std::true_type,const A<T>& t) {
    std::cout<<"2"<<std::endl;
  }

  template <class T>
  void func(std::false_type,const T& t) {
    std::cout<<"1"<<std::endl;
  }
}

template <typename T>
void func(const T& t) {
  details::func(has_template_base<A,T>,t);
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce734aa7476d06af).

Comment: Curiously enough the problem specific solution doesn't work when another layer is added (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3c9a3b7f5a9460d). The traits however does...

Comment: I understand how the type trait works but how is the compiler able to deduce `Ts...` in `operator()`? Just by looking at the type hierarchy of `X` (from `has_template_base`)?

Comment: @Timo Template argument deduction is applied both against a type and its base types?  Eventually it tests `A<Ts...>*` it against `A<int>*`, and deduces `{Ts...}` to be `{int}`.

Comment: @StoryTeller The ambiguity is a bit of a pain.  I swear I had it working, but I'm having issues now.  I'm nixing that solution.